# Find any two periods and any non-digit character in regex string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm close, I just need a few tips on getting this correct.
Essentially I want to return true if I have the string 1.0, but return false if I have the string 1..0 or ANY character other than numbers.

So I need to match any character other than numbers but I can also match 2 or more periods.

EX:

```
1.0 => true
2.000004 => true
foobar => false
2..0 => false
2 => true
2.0.0.0.0 => false
```

I currently have been toying with this: /[a-zA-Z]|.{2,}/

my translation is that it matches any letters, or any 2 periods..
It works, but it only matches 2 consecutive periods, so the following happens

```
2.0.0.0.0 => true (I want to be false, as in I want to match this)
```

I would like to use \D instead of [a-zA-Z] to potentially avoid any strange ASCII characters but a period is in the subset of \D but not in [a-zA-Z]

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: 1.222.. true or false ?

Comment: I should have been more specific, False. 1.222 => true   1.222. =>false   1..22 => false  .1. => false   .1 => true

Comment: What about negative numbers, e.g. `-1.23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested all your options

```
^\.{1}?[0-9]*\.{1}?[0-9]+$
```

http://rubular.com/r/5ll1Grhy6H

If you need negative numbers:

```
^[.-]{1}?[0-9]*\.{1}?[0-9]+$
```

http://rubular.com/r/LLOjq1pIUY

Answer (score 0):

Here is an opposite approach:

```
/\.{2,}|[^\d\.-]|(\d\.){2,}|\.\z|.-/
```

This regex will find "incorrect" strings, that contain:

- two or more dots close to each other
- characters that are not: digits, dot, dash (for negative numbers)
- two or more groups "digit-dot" (like in 2.0.0.0.0)
- dot as a last character
- dash not in the first position

All strings that return `true` in this comparison

```
string !~ /\.{2,}|[^\d\.-]|(\d\.){2,}|\.\z|.-/
```

should be valid numbers (floats or integers)